# THE demonstrative as a single word?

Tags: grammar

Like the definite article, recently I started to see what are traditionally known as demonstatives not as a group of words but rather as a single word.

If you analyze it as an inflected word with a variable function, it simplifies a lot of logic.

In other words, the demostrative inflects for number, singular and plural, and *distance*, near or far, producing the following four forms:

> this, that, these, those

In addition, the demostrative, can have one of two grammatical functions. It can function as a determiner:

> *These* books

Or it can funtion as a pronoun:

> *This* is better.

If inflected verbs can be thought of as one word, why not other words with a common stem and meaning?

Comment: *this, that, these, those* can be pronouns, *the* is not normally so

Comment: @Clare I wasn't claiming that. I meant The definite article is a single word, theres only one.

Comment: 'Yon' may be archaic, but it's not obsolete.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's obsolete around these parts.

Comment: @Dan Bron That's why it's best to check in a dictionary, to avoid parochialism.